# Collapse side panel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I collapse side panel when viewed on smaller screens, so that "panel-header" becomes a toggle button. I.e instead of hamburger button, get "Filter Students" button which will expand "panel-body".

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-header">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Filter Students</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="search">
        <h3>SEARCH KEYWORD</h3>
        <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
 <div class="filter-categories">
     <ul class="filter">
       <li>Graphic Design</li>
        <li>Online Marketing</li>
        <li>Video Commercials</li>
        <li>Technology</li>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Translation</li>
    </ul>
</div>                  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do this with jQuery [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). The sidebar hides when the viewport is reduced to under 768px and can be hidden on click on larger viewports (this could be disabled if need be).

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #DB1849;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
.btn-default#menu-toggle,
.btn-default#menu-toggle:hover,
.btn-default#menu-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  color: #DB1849;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav .sidebar-brand {
  text-align: left;
}
.sidebar-nav .sidebar-brand img {
  width: 75px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul > li {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul > li > a {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <img src="http://kodi.wiki/images/c/c1/Thumbnail-light-transparent.png" alt="KODI">
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#nope" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drop1"> Something<span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul id="drop1" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
          <li><a href="about-us">Something</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="our-journey">Something</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="where-we-are-going">Something</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="what-we-do">Something</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="the-building">Something</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="volunteer">Something</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>KODI</h1>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```